# how to write if else within click function in javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a div with class "post" that has a bunch of text in it with no height specified.

```
.post {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
    background-color: #AAA;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

With jQuery I want to initially add a second class "postLess" that specifies a height of 300px. And therefore hides part of the text.

```
.postLess {
    height: 300px;
}
```

When the "read more" button is clicked I would like to remove "postLess" and add "postMore" so that the height is set to "auto" and shows the full text.

```
.postMore {
    height: auto;
}
```

Then of course I want it to remove class "postMore" and add back class "postLess" when the button is clicked a second time. Here is my jQuery. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $('.post').addClass('postLess');
    $('.readMore').click(function() {
        if ($('.post').hasClass('postLess')) {
            $('.post').removeClass('postLess').addClass('postMore');
        }
        else if ($('.post').hasClass('postMore')) {
            $('.post').removeClass('postMore').addClass('postLess');
        }
    });
```

And here is the important part of my HTML down to the first two ".post"'s

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Switchback</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <p>
                    Ut neque tellus, dapibus bibendum tempor quis, gravida vitae nisl.     Pellentesque erat elit, ullamcorper in accumsan id, ullamcorper in lectus. Nullam nec augue 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Nunc facilisis lacus vel enim fringilla consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur vitae sem mauris. 
                </p>
            </div> <!-- end div id="sidebar" -->
            <div id="posts">
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="postImg" style="background-image: url('img/pic1.png');">
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse purus lorem, viverra sed blandit non, vulputate in sem. Donec laoreet turpis id lectus 
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="readMore">read&nbsp;more&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="postImg" style="background-image: url('img/pic2.png');">
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec felis 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Sed ornare, velit ac dignissim lacinia, dui mauris suscipit enim, quis viverra metus elit id quam. Sed quis tellus nulla. Nam pulvinar ante at felis lobortis eleifend. 
                        <a href="#" class="readMore">read&nbsp;more&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Other than caching the `$('.post')` selector there is nothing wrong with your code. Does it not work? You could also simplify it a little by removing the `if` condition and using `$('.post').toggleClass('postMore postLess');`

Comment: If you have more than one `<div>` with the class `post`, the `.hasClass()` function will return true if *any* of them have the `postLess` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element starts out with one class, and you'd like to remove that class and add a different class and vice versa, just use toggleClass() to toggle both classes, and it should do the job for you :

```
$('.readMore').on('click', function() {
    $('.post').toggleClass('postLess postMore');
});
```

If there are more than one `.post` element, you'll need to target them individually.

If the .post element is a parent of the .readMore element, you can use closest() :

```
$('.readMore').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.post').toggleClass('postLess postMore');
});
```

If it's a child, you can use context : `$('.post', this).toggleClass('postLess postMore');`

Answer (score 0):

This is a more efficient way off doing it just toggle the class on an off no if statements required

```
$('.post').addClass('postLess');
    $('.readMore').click(function() {
           $('.post').toggleClass('postLess postMore');
            return false;      
    });
```

Also if your post more button is within the post div, you can do the following. This means you can have multiple instances of a post div running independently.

```
$('.post').addClass('postLess');
        $('.readMore').click(function() {
               $(this).parent().toggleClass('postLess postMore');
               return false;      
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it only fot the post you want to read, do don't use `$('.post')` but use `$(this).parents('.post')` instead.

So the complete solution would be :

```
$('.readMore').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.post').toggleClass('postLess postMore');
});
```

Is it for a wordpress blog? I like this idea very much, I might try it on mine!

Comment: How do you know that `.post` is a parent of `.readMore`, and since `parents()` searches all the way to the document level, how do you know that there are'nt more `.post` elements as parents etc.

Comment: It is an assumption, you are right. AS I do use Wordpress a lot, I know you put a "Read more" only on a page where multiple posts are presents, and they are siblings.

Others suggest to use .parent() but I am not sure the .post is the direct parent of the .readMore.

Your solution will only work if there is only one .post in the page, which makes no sense to have a "Read More" on such a page...